# Drag and Drop angular without using array

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material

I need to know if it is possible to use the drag and drop of angular with methods that return me arrays, and still manage to connect two drag and drop.

something like:

```
<div *ngIf="render">
    <div class="container-drag-drop">
        <div (cdkDropListDropped)="dropFirst($event)" cdkDropList #free="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[dontFree]" [cdkDropListData]="firstMethod()" class="list-drag-drop">
            <div class="box-drag-drop" *ngFor="let codTemp of firstMethod()" cdkDrag>{{codTemp}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="render">
    <div class="container-drag-drop">
        <div (cdkDropListDropped)="dropSecond($event)" cdkDropList #dontFree="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[free]" [cdkDropListData]="secondMethod()" class="list-drag-drop">
            <div class="box-drag-drop" *ngFor="let codTemp of secondMethod()" cdkDrag>{{codTemp}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is possible to do something like this, where I can drop the items from my array1 by triggering the dropSecond event and the opposite happens also by triggering the dropFirst event ?

Comment: Isn't it working? If not, please give details of the issue you're having.

Comment: So this is not working, because drag and drop works only with arrays from what I read, but with those methods that return array does not work.

Comment: Are you able to create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) for that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because of ngIf but I wanted the opinion of you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odf9es

Comment: So far, there is no logic implemented on `dropDone` or `dropTodo` to move items between both lists. If you implement this logic, this should be fine. Check the `drop` method implementation on [this example](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#transferring-items-between-lists).

Comment: Yes it has no logic yet, but note that when moving an item to another list, it does not make the move much less triggers the correct event. And when I try to move something from the `todo` list to the `done` list it does not trigger the `dropDone` event. Try to do the following test move the items inside the list and visualize which event will be called and then try to move to another list and see which event will be called

Comment: Yes, it seems to be related to `*ngIf` (also, you should update your question to include *ngIf on the code sample). I've replace both `divs` containing the *ngIf directive with a single `ng-container` and I think that is what you're expecting. Forked your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odf9es-xem1is?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html)

Comment: So we found the problem, really are the `*ngIf`, but would this be a bug or the expected behavior? Anyway I found my mistake and I will correct it, thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug or a expected behaviour, didn't go too deep on it, but it seems to be related on angular handling the ng-container on a different way than other html tags. If you want to investigate it deeper, suggest you to search for that, or create an issue on angular material's github repository.